# VB.NET Datagridview sort without sorting totals

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is a cross tab. When the user click on one of the column headers I'd like to sort the datagridview, but I don't want the final (total) row to be sorted.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a custom DataGridView from XCeed.  It has a summary row built into the control.  Seems like overkill, but hey, what're you gonna do right?

Answer (score 1):

You can temporary take the last line out of the list by assigning it to a temp grid-line and do a `.RemoveAt(lineID)` on your grid, then sort, and finally append the temp grid-line back on the grid.

Comment: So frustrating.  This should work, but the DGV is bound to a datatable. When I remove the row (r) from the datatable (dt), it basically sets r to null.  So when I insert the row back into dt, I get a line of 0s.

`dt = Datagridview1.DataSource
dim r as datarow
For each dr as datarow in dt.rows
 if dr(0).tostring.contains("Total: ") then
  r = dr
  dt.remove(dr)
  exit for
 end if

dt.rows.add(r)`